Is RIGHT JOIN supported in parallel hash join now?
I've read this series of articles regarding the joins.
In the post, there is an overview table suggesting that Parallel hash join doesn't support RIGHT JOIN. However, as I've tested it out on my ClickHouse Cloud environment, there were no errors thrown out, and the performance seems to be better when using Parallel hash join. Below are some sample queries I used.
SELECT *
FROM table_a
RIGHT JOIN table_b 
ON table_a.id = table_b.id
SETTINGS join_algorithm = 'auto', max_threads = 2, max_bytes_in_join = 50000000000;

Duration: 101 seconds, Memory usage: 6.43 GiB
SELECT *
FROM table_a
RIGHT JOIN table_b 
ON table_a.id = table_b.id
SETTINGS join_algorithm = 'parallel_hash', max_threads = 2, max_bytes_in_join = 50000000000;

Duration: 56 seconds, Memory usage: 25.63 GiB
Is the Parallel hash join supported for RIGHT JOIN, or is there something wrong with what I did?
Update:
Added EXPLAIN SELECT as suggested by @Slach
For the first query,
Expression ((Project names + (Projection + DROP unused columns after JOIN)))
Join (JOIN FillRightFirst)
Expression ((JOIN actions + Change column names to column identifiers))
ReadFromMergeTree (table_a)
Expression ((JOIN actions + Change column names to column identifiers))
ReadFromMergeTree (table_b)

For the second one,
Expression ((Project names + (Projection + DROP unused columns after JOIN)))
Join (JOIN FillRightFirst)
Expression ((JOIN actions + Change column names to column identifiers))
ReadFromMergeTree (table_a)
Expression ((JOIN actions + Change column names to column identifiers))
ReadFromMergeTree (table_b)


which clickhouse-server version do you use?
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#join_algorithm
documentations still say 'auto' is hash trying first

It's the ClickHouse cloud - current version is 24.8. Yes, that means the first query tries hash join (and it likely used hash cause we have more than enough memory for that). However, the second query where I put join_algorithm = 'parallel_hash' in the setting, this one performs better than the first one (which used hash) so I'm assuming join_algorithm = 'parallel_hash' works on that. That's why I'm confused since it's the RIGHT JOIN one and the documentation says they don't support join_algorithm = 'parallel_hash' for RIGHT JOIN

you can try to EXPLAIN SELECT ... maybe it will helpfull

Thanks for the suggestion. I've added to the post. They actually look identical
